# access readme files from github using jsonp angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, github, jsonp

i am working on angular app that needs to display readme.md files from GitHub do is it possible to get via Json callback in angular 
i tried repositories and i got it but how for readme.md files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked example **github** api [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents).

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/2gzr6zea/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, Slim,$sce) {
    Slim.getReadme().then(function(resp) {
      $scope.readme = $sce.trustAsHtml(resp.data);
    }).catch(function(resp) {
      console.log("catch", resp);
    });
  })
  .service('Slim', function($http) {
    return {
      getReadme: function() {
        return $http.get("https://api.github.com/repos/slimphp/Slim/readme", {
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <pre ng-bind-html="readme"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you need to beautifully display **markdown**.

For example [angular-markdown-directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive)

Comment: thanks and how can i create custom readme.md files dynamically

Comment: Learn [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file). It's a great documentation!